# What is the best Homebrew formula to extend macOS' disk formatting support to non-native disk types like ext4?

Tags: linux, macos, homebrew

As macOS' disk utility only supports Mac OS Extended, MS-DOS, and exFAT, what formula could I install through Homebrew to gain access to additional disk type formats like ext4?

Answer (score 0):

macOS's built in disk utility only supports specific filesystems.
[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-dsku19ed921c/mac)

Install osxfuse:
`brew install --cask osxfuse`

If you receive an error similar to:
`installer: Error - The FUSE for macOS installation package is not compatible with this version of macOS.`

You will need to seek a commercial version of Fuse with ext2/3/4 support. From Big Sur forward, Apple limited access to kernel extensions and added additional security features that osxfuse requires.

Finally install fuse-ext2:
[fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2)